# Microsoft Surface 1.0 How to create a contact from RAW image and Emgu CV

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, pixelsense, emgucv

I'm working on Microsoft Surface 1.0 and working with leds to create a pen for tabletops.
My question is, how can i set the minimum size of a blob that can be recognized by the surface?

I mean, if I've thresholded the RAW image of surface cameras and show just the LED i want to be recognized and saved into a `CircleF[]` array, can I create a contact giving the coordinates of the circle I've saved?.

The point is, when the LED touch the surface, the blob disappear because is too small so it can't be recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supported way to customize this

Comment: Hi, I think there is a way, you say the blob is present after you threshold the RAW image. The blob then apparently disappears when the LED touches the surface. Is the LED still visible before thresholding? if so then correct your thresholding to stop it being suppressed at this point (you could also use adaptive thresholding if you need different values at distances). You then say you wish to create "a contact giving the coordinates of the circle I've saved" ok for each frame then I assume you wish to add a position to your CircleF[] array this is fairly simply (List). There's always a way

Comment: the led is always visible, in my threshold is still detectable, it is not recognized by the surface. I did what you said, but i dont know how to change surface criteria of recognition of blobs. And, as I can see,  there is no way to create a new simulated contact while processing just a RAW image, cause is managed just by the surface